# MySql backup and restoration

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

Trying to find out how people do a full backup/restore procedure: The user defined database schema and data can be easily backed up via mysqldump, but what about the master tables and data? i.e. if the server goes completely bananas, how can I rebuild the database, i.e. including all the settings in Mysql? is it just a matter of dumping/importing the information_schema and mysql databases + restore my.cnf ? (innodb or MyISAM, not ISAM)

--

edit: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't back up information_schema, but otherwise, yes, keep a copy of your my.cnf and a dump of the mysql db tables and log settings.  To do this do:

```
mysqldump -u$user -p$pass --all-databases > db_backup.sql
```

If you're going to restore to the 100% same version of MySQL, you could also backup by shutting down your server and doing a full copy of the contents of /var/lib/mysql (or wherever your data files are) along with your my.cnf file.   Then just drop the copy back in place when you want to go live and turn on your server.

Comment: and you restore it by running the db_backup.sql you obtained