# How to deploy existing MySql Data to Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to migrate my existing web database (developed using MySQL) from GoDaddy server to Amazon AWS. Please suggest what is the best way to achieve.

Any pointer or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways in which you can run a MySQL Server in AWS

- Amazon RDS
- MySQL in EC2

In either of the case you, in the perspective of backup and restore, you can consider them as yet another MySQL Instance. To migrate existing there are several tools ( Open Source as well ) to perform the backup and restore.

The steps to do a backup and restore would go this way

- take the DDL dump ( DB and Schema ) and execute it in AWS RDS / EC2 Instance
- Take the Data dump ( .sql file ) from the existing MySQL Instance ( GoDaddy )
- Execute the Data dump in the new MySQL Instance

These are few links which provide

- MySQL Backup & Recovery - [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html)
- MySQL Dumper - [Link](http://www.mysqldumper.net/)
- MySQL backup and restore from command line - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823841/mysql-backup-and-restore-from-command-line)
- MySql backup and restoration - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607056/mysql-backup-and-restoration)

Comment: Thank you Naveen, all these reference helped and i have successfully transferred/deployed all services and database. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks.. One more query - i am done with all stuff and now i want to set DNS name (web site name) to my EC2 instance Public DNS value, i have just read on docs that i need to set "Elastic IP" - will you be able to add any ref link or pointer on this. Thank You.

Comment: Hello Naveen, To change DNS name i found this ref doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

As per this changing "Hostname" value in "network" configuration file should work..

Comment: Both the above comments mean 2 different things, you need not consider the 2nd comment for your requirement. You attach an Elastic IP to your instance from the AWS Console itselt [http://goo.gl/jrMzaH]. Once you are done with that; you can take that IP and put that in your Domain name management i.e. [ your side domain - example.com - from service like GoDaddy or provider where you bought that ]